# Exporting Scala project as jar from Eclipse

Tags: java, scala, compilation

I have a Scala project and I would like to export it as a jar.

*1. At first I tried creating a Java class for the project as an entry point

```
public class JMain {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Java main calling Scala main");
  SMain.main(new String[] {""}); //SMain.main is the actual *main*
```

and this worked fine and dandy when launched from Eclipse, but when I export it as jar it'll give me 18 exceptions or so. I do now know how to replicate then "environment" in which Eclipse manages to launch this and I'm prety sure it relies on the fact that Scala is on my system already - I need a self contained jar with everything packed in there.

*2. My second try consisted of trying what *lach* suggested here [How to deploy a Scala project from Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921600/how-to-deploy-a-scala-project-from-eclipse)
namely:

```
public class JMain {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Java Main");
  List<String> argList = new ArrayList<String>();
  argList.add("fully.qualified.ClassName"); //???
  for (String s : args) argList.add(s);
  scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(argList.toArray(new String[0]));
```

This time it won't even run from Eclipse, although it gives only 6 or so exceptions starting with the famous **NoClassDefFoundError**. I have a feeling I'm not getting *fully.qualified.ClassName* right. *3. If the *main* Scala class is called "Dis.scala" and is located in package "pack" shouldn't this *fully.qualified.ClassName* be "pack.Dis"?

I'm using Jre 1.6 and Scala 2.9.2
EDIT: I have included all external imported jars, even scala-library.jar - everything is nice and packed in the jar

P.S. I am not familiar with Ant or Maven or Sbt. I just want my Scala project jared - if possible without getting into hairy things.

Comment: You might find it simpler in the long run to put a modest amount of effort up-front to set up an Sbt (or Maven) build, life becomes very much easier from that point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:
1. Create scala project
2. Create Wrapper java project 
3. Add the scala-library.jar to you java project build path.

So you only need the 3rd step in addition since the rest looks similar to what I did. Then you can happily use: java - jar file.jar

EDIT:
How to create a JAR File which contains Scala/Code which can be consumed by another Java Project, using Scala - Eclipse IDE.

1. Create a new Scala Project and define an object with a main method as entry point.
2. Now create a new Java Project and add your Scala Project to the new ones buildpath. Additionally add the scala-library.jar to the Java project.
3. Now create a Wrapper class in the java project which calls your entry point class from the scala lib. Run the wrapper class to create a eclipse run configuration and test if you can call the scala project.
4. Use the Export->Java->Runnable JAR file, Wizard now on the wrapper project.The eclipse run configuration will be used as entrypoint into the JAR. Depending on your needs you may want to :
   extract required libraries into generated JAR
   or
   Package required libraries into generated JAR

Finally you get a complete packaged JAR which you can use like this:

java - jar wrapped.jar

Comment: could you detail your answer so that it helps others, not just the original poster?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was relatively straightforward.

> 1. Develop and test the project using the scala IDE (or eclipse for java).
> 2. once ready, generate the jar for the project using file -> export method.

for submitting the spark (i was writing something for spark), i just had to mention --class option for specifying the main class for the jar.

hope to help.